# Задача на последовательность чисел

Tags: java

Задача:

Выведите "лесенку" из членов последовательности от единицы до n, n > 0.
На вход подается натуральное число n. Желательно использовать цикл for.
Вывести всю последовательность чисел. Последовательность должна выводится от меньшего к
большему(в виде лесенки).

```
input 1:  5

output 1:
1
1 2
1 2 2
1 2 2 3
1 2 2 3 3


Input 2: 1

1

Output 2:

1
```

Мой код:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        
        int n = sc.nextInt();
     
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            // System.out.println("\n"); 
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
               for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
                    System.out.print(j);
               
                 }
               
             }
           System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
122
122333
1223334444
122333444455555
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129167/discussion-on-question-by-sstwg----).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    int k = 1;
    int l = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                l += k;
            }
            System.out.print(l+" ");
        }
        l = 1;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: может быть можно и избавиться от некоторых переменных, что бы сократить код, но об это я не думал.